# Access the sharepoint list items using webview of o365 authentication with

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am trying to Access the sharepoint list items using webview of o365 authentication with. I have no idea what am I missing.

```
public class Webservice extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webservice);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_Sharepoint_Login);

        webView.loadUrl("https://"mydomain".sharepoint.com/");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                String Cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("https://"mydomain".sharepoint.com/sites/WizardsGroupIntranet/Operations/SitePages/Home.aspx");

                if (Cookies.contains("rtFa")) {
                    String[] seperated = Cookies.split(";");
                    boolean RTFA = false;
                    boolean FedAuth = false;
                    String RTFA_Value = "";
                    String FedAuth_Value = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i <= seperated.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (seperated[i].contains("rtFa") && RTFA != true) {
                            SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Webservice.this);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
                            RTFA_Value = seperated[i].substring(6);
                            editor.putString("rtFa", RTFA_Value);
                            editor.commit();
                            RTFA = true;
                        }
                        if (seperated[i].contains("FedAuth") && FedAuth != true) {
                            SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Webservice.this);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
                            FedAuth_Value = seperated[i].substring(9);
                            editor.putString("FedAuth", FedAuth_Value);
                            editor.commit();
                            FedAuth = true;
                        }
                        if (RTFA == true && FedAuth == true) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;

            }
        });


    }
}

/*Async Task*/

public class AsyncTask extends Webservice

{
    SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AsyncTask.this);
    static String RTFA;
    static String FedAuth;

    public AsyncTask(Context context) {
        RTFA = shared.getString("rtFa", "No Value");
        FedAuth = shared.getString("FedAuth", "No Value");
    }
    //DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://"mydomain".sharepoint.com/sites/"mydomain"Intranet/Operations/_api/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Jumper')/Title");

    //New Code

    public String httpGet(String method) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://"mydomain".sharepoint.com/sites/"mydomain"Intranet/Operations/_api/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Jumper')/Title");

    /* headers */
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    /* authentication */
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                RTFA + ":" + FedAuth);
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                credentials);

    /* execute */
        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpget);
    /* return response */
        return TextHelper.GetText(httpResponse);
    }
}

         class TextHelper {
            public static String GetText(InputStream in) {
                String text = "";
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    text = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                } finally {
                    try {

                        in.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
                return text;
            }


            public static String GetText(HttpResponse response) {
                String text = "";
                try {
                    text = GetText(response.getEntity().getContent());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                return text;


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I need you to be a little more specific about the nature of your problem. Are you having difficulty retrieving the cookies? or is that you're getting an authentication error when you attempt to perform the Http get.

I also notice that you pass in a `httpResponse` to `gettext`, while `gettext` seems to expect an input stream. Pass in `[httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()]` instead.